# How to fix " My first scan value is not same as my second scan value and the value scan in HTML is not same as value scan in notepad?"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using scanner detection device. Currently, I have barcode with this value `2345345 A1`. So when I scanned into my notepad or text editor, the output will be like this `2345345 A1` which is the right barcode value.

The problem is :

- When the first time I scanned the barcodes into my HTML page, the output value will be like this `2345345A1` . This shows that the spaces-bar already missing. How to make the spaces-bar become a character in HTML? So that the scanned value will be like exact value of barcodes.
- Next, when the second time I scanned the barcodes into my HTML page, the output value will be like this `2345345` . This shows that the second words of barcode is missing. So, how to make my second time scan value is same as my first time scan value?

This is picture first scan:
[image: First Time Scan]

This is picture second scan:
[image: Second Time Scan]

This is picture when I scan into text editor:
[image: Result Scan in Notepad]

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).scannerDetection({
  timeBeforeScanTest: 200, // wait for the next character for upto 200ms
  startChar: [120], // Prefix character for the cabled scanner (OPL6845R)
  endChar: [13], // be sure the scan is complete if key 13 (enter) is detected
  avgTimeByChar: 40, // it's not a barcode if a character takes longer than 40ms
  preventDefault: true,
  ignoreIfFocusOn: '.scannerOff',
  onKeyDetect: function(event) {
    console.log(event.which);
    return false;
  }
  onComplete: function(numberBarcode) {
    validScan = true;

    alert("Job Start");
    $('#fullbarcode').text(numberBarcode);
    $('#barcode').text(numberBarcode);
    var res = numberBarcode.substring(0, 7);
    document.getElementById("barcode").innerHTML = res;
    $('#zone').text(numberBarcode);
    var subStr = numberBarcode.slice(-3);;
    document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML = subStr;

  }, // main callback function ,    
  onError: function(string) {
    $('#userInput').val($('#userInput').val() + string);
  }
});
```

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 40%;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2
}

th {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/home/mimos/Videos/jQuery/jquery.scannerdetection.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/kabachello/jQuery-Scanner-Detection/master/jquery.scannerdetection.js"></script>
<p><strong> Scan BarCode : </strong></p>
<input id="userInput" type="text" resetObject.autofocus="false" readonly/><br/><br/><br/>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Full Barcode</th>
    <th>Barcode</th>
    <th>Zone</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <p id=fullbarcode type="text" readonly/><br/><br/><br/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id=barcode type="text" readonly/><br/><br/><br/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <p id="zone" type="text" readonly/><br/><br/><br/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: There's a syntax error in your code. You're missing a `,` between the `onKeyDetect` and `onComplete` properties

Comment: thanks for notice it. But nothing's happen. Because I still get different value when I scan the barcodes two times. btw, thanks! @RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 0):

```
var res = numberBarcode.substring(0, 7);
document.getElementById("barcode").innerHTML = res;
$('#zone').text(numberBarcode);
var subStr = numberBarcode.slice(-3);;
document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML = subStr;
```

you split it first and ask then why there are missing characters?
how is just `document.getElementById("zone").innerHTML = numberBarcode;` ?

Comment: I already edit the post. You may refer the picture of the result. First scan is different with second time scan. I totally miserable with this. Please help me. I wanna cry.

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar issue where it was removing the spaces in the barcode.
We solved this by focusing on the text box on any key press:

```
onKeyDetect: function (event) {
    $("#serialNumber").focus();
    return false;
},
```

Where `#serialNumber` is the id of the input element

To keep the spaces, you can surround your text with `<pre></pre>`